# Is there a way to stop “Ctrl+C” from closing a tab when running Git Bash in Console2?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, git-bash, console2

My goal is to have a terminal with Unix commands (e.g. `ls` instead of `dir`), color, and working keys in my Windows 7 machine. My current attempt at getting this to work is using **Git Bash** in Console2. I created a new tab with:

```
Title: Git Bash
Icon: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico
Shell: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i
Startup dir: C:\Users\evesforeva
```

**Git Bash** gives me the Unix commands. Adding ansicon gives me color. But when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it closes the whole tab. I need it to stop processes like `rails server` without closing the tab. I also tried different combinations of swapping `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` for `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` for `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe` and got the same results.

A direct solution to the problem would be much appreciated, but if that's not possible, I’ll take anything that provides Unix commands, color, and working keys. I also tried using **Git Bash** directly with minTTY, but the arrow keys don't work and `irb` exits after one command. I even went as far as trying to install Ubuntu. My HP Probook 650 G1 won't let me change any of the BOIS settings, so neither dual-booting nor VirtualBox worked.

**How do I prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from closing the tab when running Git Bash in Console2?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

1. "cmd.exe /c" in your command is superfluous. Remove it completely.
2. Update to the latest git-for-windows. It has git-cmd.exe wrapper. To run it properly there are switches, something like "git-cmd.exe --cmd=/use/bin/sh.exe"

   3. Not sure about Console... Check your associated action for Ctrl+C hotkey. It may be configured improperly.
3. Why do not give a try to ConEmu?

Comment: ConEmu is perfect! Worked for me too!

Comment: ConEmu v220807 does not work for me

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
Shell: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe" --login -i
```

The bash.exe inside \Git\usr\bin seems to handle Ctrl-C normally.

*64bit Win7 using Git for Windows 2.6.1

Comment: Thanks for a proper answer! Possibly something to do with the new mintty shell.

Comment: Don't forget the quotes, and don't forget to clear the CTRL-C command from the Console2 Hotkeys (clear, assign, ok)

Answer (score 0):

In short the solution is:

> Take a terminal that works.

1. I find a few working [`gitbash v2.32.0`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.32.0.windows.1) or [`gitbash v2.34.1`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.34.1.windows.1)

The latest available `gitbash` currently is `v2.38.1`. But only the old one is working correctly with `Vagrant(Oracle VM)`. The strange thing is that the latest one (`gitbash  v2.38.1`) is working fine with SSH connections to AWS EC2 instances.

2. Alternatively. `Windows PowerShell` is working fine with Vagrant(Oracle VM).

---

If someone needs my **bad experience**, here it is.
The following terminals DON'T WORK

- gitbash v2.38.1 (latest for now)
- gitbash V2.36.0
- ConEmu v220807 Alhpa (latest for now)
- cmder v1.3.20.1282 (latest for now)

Comment: [It is not acceptable to post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/355310).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, it happens quite often, when one solution fixes a few issues.